# Getting column number of cell with particular text using vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image: screeshot of the excel]Hi i need to get column of a cell with the text as ACTION.

My current code is as below.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim actionColName As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & "+ " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In the above code there is a condition as below 
    If Target.Column = 3 Then

Instead of hard coding the value with 3 i would like to apply this logic for the complete column which contains the value **ACTION**  in one of its cell in that column.

Comment: Can you pls post a sample file

Comment: I have posted the sample file

Comment: where is the sample file?

Comment: i have attached the screenshot.The requirement is that if i select two values from dropdown then two values will be added to cell with "+".Suppose if try to edit the cell with some new value which is not in the list then i m facing the issue.The result is like the second cell in the attached sheet.The values are getting replicated.I did not find any way to add the file,hence i added screenshot.

Comment: @bredttdj  Any pointers for the solution

Answer (score 8):

Use a `Find` to determine the (first) column containing *Action*

```
Sub GetAction()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Action", , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Found in column " & rng1.Column
Else
MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks its working.Could you please let me know how to edit the values in the dropdownlist on the fly instead of updating the list the in the excel?

Comment: Thanks its working.The problem i am facing is that i am applying the above logic on particular column.That Column's each cell is a drop down.For the first time i will select one value from dropdown and secondtime if i select other value in that dropdown from the same cell then the new value will appended with "+" symbol with the existing value.while adding the second value.Example i have selected a value "one" from the drop down.and if i want to add a new value something like "THOUSAND" to the drop down on the fly then i am seeing as one+one+THOUSAND instead of one+THOUSAND.